# Консольное приложение (С) Неправильное отображение символов в консоли

Tags: c

Всем привет. Создал проект. При запуске вот такая беда.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Укажите пожалуйста на причину этой проблемы. Пытался гуглить, безрезультатно.
Код выложить не могу, так как достаточно емкий.

Comment: Ну очевидно же: причина в коде программы...

Comment: - Доктор, у меня что-то болит... - Ну, выпейте какое-нибудь лекарство... Понятно же, что ошибка в программе, но в какой - вы не указали, исходник **проблемного места** не привели...

Comment: @John (или Дарья, как вас там?) - любые объемы исходников можно выложить на github (привыкайте к VCS!) или на pastebin.

Comment: Похоже, у вас указатель на случайную область памяти используется в виде строки. Или вы в сишной строке используете финальный ноль.

Comment: @VladD Да, дело оказалось в финальном нуле =)

Comment: Ну вот и хорошо. Дарье привет от нас.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выглядит как вывод случайной памяти. Поскольку в тексте присутствуют другие строки, можно предположить, что у вас в сишной строке потерялся финальный `\0`.